# NSFetchedResultsController is receiving didChangeObject for relationship changes?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview that displays `Event` (core data backed object). I have another table somewhere that shows `Ticket`. Events have many tickets.

When I create a new ticket, save it to the persistent store, the tableview controlling the `Event` receives a `didChangeObject` notification. I don't want it to. Nothing is actually changing that the table view should be concerned about. I happen to create/change/modify tickets quite a bit, and according to Time Profiler, I'm losing some precious time on the main thread by handling those didChangeObject's.

I debugged it, and it seems to happen here:

```
ticket.event = event;
```

I set breakpoints before and after that line, `po`'ing the `ticket.managedObjectContext.updatedObjects` to the console, and the event appears as soon as I assign the event to the ticket.

Comment: Do you have (the recommended) reverse relationship setup between event and tickets?  If so, that's what is triggering the update notification for event.  A change in a related object won't trigger an FRC, but a change in the relationship will (because that relationship is a property of the related object).

Comment: I do. Alright that makes sense as I can foresee many cases where you would want the notification.... Maybe I can experiment with using different managed object contexts and changing  the way I save to the persistent store.

Comment: Would it be a good solution to set the fetchedresultscontroller.delegate to nil when the view disappears, and then set it back and do a reloadData/performFetch on viewWillAppear? Does that solve my performance problem?

Comment: That is a good way to do it.  I worked on an app that had a similar problem (persistent VC, even when off-screen), and that's what we did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm going to use the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"end_date >= %@", [NSDate date]];
  self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

  NSError *error;
  BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
  if (!success)
    NSLog(@"ERROR: performing fetch: %@", error);

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  // we are not interested in changes when this view is offscreen
  self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}
```

Though longterm I am working on a solution to only save the context when the user wants to commit their changes, because I have a bunch of -/+ UISteppers in cells, and it would make more sense I think to have a `UIButton` that animates into the cell that when pressed, will save the context, rather than saving the context every time the `UIStepper` changes.